# How can I display additional boot and shutdown information on the Windows 7 welcome screen?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-registry, shutdown

There is a small tweak, I believe it is a registry key, that allows to display additional information on the *Welcome* and *Shutting down* screens of Windows 7 (and most likely Vista, too). I have activated this tweak on one of my systems; unfortunately I forgot how I did it, and I can't seem to find the website that originally gave me that information.

Usually, the Windows 7 welcome screen will just display "Welcome" when logging in. With the tweak activated, my Welcome screen gives status information such as "Loading user settings" or "Preparing desktop". When shutting down, the default screen simply says "Shutting down". With the tweak activated, it gives additional status information such as "Stopping Windows services". This appears the same way that Windows gives information when updates are installed or configured during the startup or shutdown procedure, and I find them quite helpful in getting a feel for what task takes how long during that process.

The only setting I was able to find is the *Boot log* checkbox on the *Boot* tab of the *msconfig* application. However, this results in Windows displaying console logs of drivers it is loading, etc., instead of the animated Windows title. This is **NOT** the setting I am looking for. The "additional boot information" setting that I have activated on this system still displays the regular animated Windows logo, and only replaces the strings displayed on the blue Welcome and Shutdown screens.

Could someone direct me to the registry key (or whatever setting) that is used to get this behaviour?

Edit: Here are a few pictures of the enhanced Welcome and Shutdown screens taken with my mobile phone—they're in German though.

[image: Waiting for User Profile Service]
<sup>Login screen "Waiting for User Profile Service"</sup>

[image: Preparing desktop]
<sup>Login screen "Preparing desktop"</sup>

[image: Stopping Windows services]
<sup>Logout screen "Stopping Windows services":</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Type `regedit` in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
2. Now go to following key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Policies\System
   ```
3. In right-side pane, look for a `DWORD VerboseStatus`. If you can't find it, create a new `DWORD` and set its name to `VerboseStatus`
4. Now change its value to any of following depending upon your requirements:

   - 0 - To Disable Verbose Status Message
   - 1 - To Enable Verbose Status Message
5. That's it. Close Registry Editor and restart your system to apply the changes.

Comment: Ha! I **just** read the question, and I knew the word 'verbose' would be in there somewhere. ;D

Comment: It should be `\Policies`, not `\ Policies` with a space?