# Changing shutdown & welcome screen on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

**Scenario:**

I wish to change the `Windows Shutdown and Welcome screen` while I shut down & switch on my system.

**My question:**

Is it possible to change the shut down screen & welcome screen with my own **swf** file?
Any tool to change my shut down screen & welcome screen and replace it with my own **swf** file?

I verified this [question which deals with changing name in welcome screen](https://superuser.com/questions/426029/how-can-i-display-additional-boot-and-shutdown-information-on-the-windows-7-welc)

Comment: Did you try using google?...http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=customize+the+welcome+screen+windows+7&oq=customize+the+welcome+screen+windows+7&gs_l=hp.3..0i8i30j0i22l5.2757.2757.1.3252.1.1.0.0.0.0.211.211.2-1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.QjB_EpH9MrI&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=d858ff3861264939&biw=1326&bih=867

Comment: Customize the logon screen...http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/03/15/windows-7-to-officially-support-logon-ui-background-customization/

Comment: A lot of link for this [Remove Windows7 Welcome and Shutdown Scrren](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/183295-remove-windows-7-welcome-shutdown-screen.html), [Login Scrren chenge](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5382-log-screen-change.html) and [How to Animate Windows Log-On Screen](http://www.ehow.com/how_5185249_animate-windows-logon-screen.html). Although last one is for XP but I hope it will run for Windows 7 as well no tested on my side.